# Angular 2 don't dectect change on an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

I develop an application with Angular 2.
 
I have a problem with dectection change in Angular. 
I explain : 
I have a component: 
 
**test.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
  <h1> Observable </h1>
  <p *ngFor="let exam of listeExamen"> {{exam.patient.name}}</p>
  <button (click)="test()">push</button>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
  listeExamen: Examen[];

  constructor(public rechercheService: RechercheService){
    this.listeExamen = [];
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.rechercheService.retrieveStudies()
      .subscribe((resultat) => {
        let patient = this.getPatient(resultat);
        let study = this.getStudy(resultat);
        this.listeExamen = this.listeExamen.concat([new Examen(patient, study)]);
      });
  }
  test(){
    console.log(this.listeExamen);
  }
}
```

This component call a service method who request a server to get result with an observable :
**recherche.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class RechercheService{
  private champ;
  private resultatRecherche;
  private dicom;
  private client;
  private services;

  constructor(){
      this.champ = infoRecherche;
      this.dicom = require("./app/dicomRequest/dicom.js");
      this.client = this.dicom.loadClient('localhost',
      11112, 'FINDSCU', 'DCM4CHEE');
      this.services = this.dicom.loadServices();
      this.client.on('error', () => {
        console.log("erreur de connexion");
      });
  }
  retrieveStudies(): Observable<any>{
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
      this.client.connect( () => {
        let cfind = new this.services.CFind();
        this.client.addService(cfind);
          let studyIds = [];
          cfind.retrieveStudies(this.champ,
          [(result) => {
            observer.next(result);
          }]);
        });
    });
}
```

The `retrieveStudies` method stack the result and component convert and stack this result in a `listeExamen`. This tab is bind to template of component.
The `Observable` make his job and stack well all results in tab.
The problem is Angular don't update the view.

Result after observable do his job: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFm6U.png)

---

---

Result after click on "appuie" :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdedq.png)

Result appear in view after emit user's event.
How update view automaticaly?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is `Hammer` is not defined

Comment: You can bind `*ngFor` directly to an `Observer` and use the `async` pipe, like: `*ngFor="let item of someObservable | async"`.

Comment: No, it's not the problem. Hammer is link to css with materialize. If i take off materialize the error "Hammer is not defined" disappear. thanks

Comment: @acdcjunior : with an `Observer`, not an `Observable`? Because I already try with an `Observable`.

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant an `Observable`, not an `Observer`, my bad.

Comment: I have resolve the problem thanks to : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100128/angular2-change-detection-inside-observable
The `NgZone` allow to lauch detection change? Thank you for help.